# Is this a Tabebuia impetiginosa – Pink Trumpet Tree Flower?

Tags: botany

Is this a Tabebuia impetiginosa – Pink Trumpet Tree Flower? From Panama.[image]

Comment: For tree identification questions please also include: 1) Pictures of the bark and leaves with an estimate of the size, 2) information about the environment within which you found the tree, and 3) an estimate of the size of the tree. All of these can be essential clues for identification. ——— If possible a picture of this plant in its environment could also be helpful. Thanks! 

Comment: All I have is this photo.

Comment: Unfortunate — please edit your post to add whatever information you do have (e.g. ecological/environmental factors) and with luck someone will be able to help ...